# Get real text from window handle

Tags: c#, c++, .net, window

I have a window handle to a child window of a PDF file.
This child window has the class "AVL_AVView", and its text is "AVPageView".

Can I somehow get the real text of this window?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obtain the window text for a window by calling `GetWindowText`. The window class name that you quote is not a standard one. It is probably a custom control of the PDF viewer program.

If you want the text of the PDF document being displayed then you are unlikely to have any success with Win32 APIs for this custom control. Perhaps the automation APIs will yield results. But a better approach might be to use a PDF library to read the document.

Comment: Hmm but OP says the window has the text "AVPageView". It could be possible that the PDF is an image with text embedded and that's perhaps why they cannot get it without OCR?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! WM_GETTEXT returns "AVPageView", so that doesn't really do what I want. But using the PDF lib is a great idea, thank you!

Comment: You did not make it terribly clear what you want so I had to guess a little. Some more clarity and detail in the question could help.